# PHP MySQL Dynamic Web pages Query

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and have learnt it through online tutorials. I am am developing my own business website. I am looking for some guidance related to making dynamic web pages. It's something like, if Db contents are like Continent>North America>USA>States>Area>City and other geography. My question is, do I have to create different tables for each content or can it be in single Table? Moreover auto generate customer id/property id is that the same what we chose in table rows. I am sorry for my stupid question.
My confusion is that if someone searches for example USA, it gonna appear as many timesas in columns where I had to use it for subordinate area or cities.

Comment: As a professional business man you should understand the value of hiring a professional web developer

Comment: Exactly, not a stupid question - but not exactly a good fit for this site either. If you want to learn more about this subject, you'll want to study database normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each table is a set of several peices of information. For each peice of information, you create a new row inside that table. You do not need a seperate table for each peice of information, however if you need a different layout for this information, you then create a new table.

I hope this helps :)

**EDIT** As requested by your comment, one thing you could do would be have a column named 'region' or something in the table, and in there you could insert information such as GB>SCO

Comment: thanks, that helps. But in case of single table can I have infinite auto increment id as little I know that it can be maximum of 255?

Comment: The INT in mysql use 4 byte storage, and range from -2147483648 to 2147483647. If you use unsigned int, the range is 0 to 4294967295. So int(255) would do just fine.

Comment: @Sebastian you can use UNSIGNED BIGINT and your autoincrement can reach 18446744073709551615. Is that enough for you?

Comment: @Sebastian Nope, as lxndr and VMai said you can reach much higher numbers.

Comment: @Sebastian: for the continents you can use an enum type, because the possibility of a change is very very low. But for all the other entities I would use separate tables.

Comment: @Sebastian, I see what you're coming at with a max of 255, It's not that the number can go up to 255, it's that the number can have up to 255 digits in it :)

Comment: @VMai, Thanks.. I will revise my resources again.. but can someone please explain me how can I enter multiple entries under one heading.. example so that i dont have to do USA>CA, USA>FL, USA>CO.. without repeating usa again in each coumn. Like lot of place within USA because if someone would search USA it would appear 50 times in rows..

Comment: @ StressedProgrammer.. I see, well that makes it quite a large number then.. I am happy..

Answer (score 0):

I would create one table for customers with autoincrementing id, and another table for purchases where each new purchase gets the customers id. like purchases.customerId
Then you can create a view where you link customers.id and purchases.customerId For example.

If you want a very nice youtube tutorial series about mysql, u really should look at this http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=49